# Opposite of filter in the computer sense

Tags: antonyms

If I have some data and want to remove all data that matches the predicate, I would call this predicate my filter condition. If I want to remove all the data that doesn't match the predicate what is the correct way of saying that? Right now I'm using retention condition. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: As Oerk explains, both cases are "a filter".  It's that simple.

Comment: But the two filters may be called "complements" of each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still a **filter**. 
It constists of a logical `NOT` followed by your original predicate.

A *filter* is something that removes some data from your view. Whether that is data that *matches* a predicate or data that *doesn't* match a predicate, you are in both cases *filtering* the data.

Comment: So you are saying to always refer to the condition to remove and if I have a condition to not remove I should convert that into a condition to remove by applying not to it?

Comment: "Show data that matches P" is exactly the same as "Hide data that does not match P". Whether you perceive the filter as "something that lets the right stuff through" or "something that holds the wrong stuff back" makes little difference, in effect a filter does both at the same time. If I want to show all even numbers, I can filter on "show all x%2=0" or "hide all x%2!=0". The effect is the same, I filter my data.

Comment: @BenjyKessler If you are filtering you are removing something from the input stream and allowing that which is not removed to pass through. The only opposite to that is to 'not filter', ie to allow the entire input stream to pass through. If you compare data filters with physical filters the same thing applies, a filter can be used either to clean a fluid (air filters and oil filters in cars for example) or to hold back that which is required letting the rest of the stream pass on (panning for gold is, essentially, a filtering operation)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's `match`.

What you filter is what you separate; what you match is what you take.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).